# My captured referals differ hugely from Google Analytics

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-analytics, http-headers

I use Google Analytics on my site and now I need to track refer-urls from some customers, i.e. I need to see the exact url they come from. My clients use a special url when referring to my site so I set up a capture of HTTP_REFER in the script on that landing page. The url the customers use is unique so there's no chance that a user accidently types that url.

The problem I face is that when i record HTTP_REFER to my database I get a lot of calls without refer, but with correct GUID and other parameters. That means that I know that they came from e.x. www.client1.com but I need to know the exact refer e.g. www.client1.com/objectx.

When I compare my database with Google Analytics the difference is huge as well. Last month Analytics said that about 1100 clicks came from my clients but my recorded clicks from my landing page are 5400. I can't see what should be wrong with my capture. It works quite simple.

1. the client has a link to my page with a unique GUID e.g
   www.mypage.com/api/123d-213-12321-23434
2. When the request hits
       my site I check the GUID to see if it's a valid customer and then
       saves the click in my db along with HTTP_REFER.
3. I then redirect them to my start page.

Does anyone have any idea why they differ so much and witch one is correct?

Comment: it could be returning clients where as Google Analytics filters it quite a lot so you wont get duplicate results

Comment: possibly but that don't explain why a lot of the calls don't have HTTP_REFER.

Comment: Could a lot of your referrers come from HTTPS URLs? Could there be a lot of search engine robots hitting your site?

Comment: Yes it could be. If I ignore my resluts without refer in my db and compare to Google Analytics they are more similar but not exactly the same.

Comment: could it be that a lot of visitors are initially going to your site from the referring URL, but then from then on, bookmarking your landing page and going directly to your site?

Comment: @CrayonViolent that could be the case but since i redirect the user as soon as I have logged the request in the database and the user then would bookmark the landing page. When using the bookmark he/she would go directly to my landing page and not hit the api script.

Comment: or, maybe they bookmark the link at the place where they click on it.  Or copy and share with friends?  IMO it looks pretty clear that a big chunk of your traffic is from going directly to the page...